# LuaC Library: Access violation with certain function(s)

Tags: c++, lua, reverse-engineering, luac

I've written a relatively basic C++ lua module using Visual Studio 2017. It exports functions from an application which can then be called from a lua script running within said application. It appeared to work fine for the most part, except for the fact that functions with more than two parameters result in an access violation. Below is a simplified variant of the code.

```
#include "lua.hpp"
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#define LUA_LIB extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int

typedef void(__fastcall* mod_Object)(void*, std::string*);
  static int lua_modObject(lua_State *L) {
  DWORD64 object = 0x155E941;
  static mod_Object newModObject = (mod_Object)(base + 0x2DF677);
  std::string mod = luaL_checkstring(L, 1);
  newModObject((LPVOID)object, &mod);
  return 0;
}
//The above function works as intended.
typedef void(__fastcall* mod_Multi_Object)(void*, std::string*,std::string*);
static int lua_mod_Multi_Object(lua_State *L) {
  DWORD64 object = 0x155E941;
  static mod_Multi_Object newModMultiObject = (mod_Multi_Object)(base +0x2DFC45);
  std::string moda = luaL_checkstring(L, 1);
  std::string modb = luaL_checkstring(L, 2);
  newModMultiObject((LPVOID)object, &moda, &modb);
  return 0;
}
//This time the above function, and any other function similar to it, results in a generic access violation or freeze.
LUA_LIB _init(lua_State *L) {
base = (DWORD64)GetModuleHandle(NULL);

lua_newtable(L);

lua_pushcfunction(L, &lua_modObject);
lua_setfield(L, -2, "objectMod");

lua_pushcfunction(L, &lua_mod_Multi_Object);
lua_setfield(L, -2, "objectMultiMod");

return 1;
}
```

The first function works as intended without crashing, whilst those which accept more than two parameters, such as the second, result in either a freeze or an access violation. Is there any particular reason as to why this might happen?

Thanks.

Comment: `std::string moda = (std::string)luaL_checkstring(L, 1);`  What is that “cast” to `std::string` supposed to do apart from cluttering your code?  Furthermore we need a MCVE which we can compile and run if you want debugging help.

Comment: Hm, you're right: not sure why I had that there. Thanks. Anyways, the code I've included makes up the one file I have in the Visual Studio project and I'm not sure how I'd include the original program. I've linked the project to the same version of that used by the program: lua-5.3-static.lib

Comment: The problem are the explicit addresses which are specific to your embedded device.  On my machine there is nothing there of course.  You should replace those by some generic objects allocated on the heap to make sure that the problem is not due to those pointers being invalid.  You should also make sure that these pointers don't accidentally alias with the Lua arguments.